# difference of 湿らす vs 潤す

Tags: word-choice

湿らす and 潤す.
Both of them have the same meaning? what's the difference between them?

Thanks,
Or

Comment: I suppose you've checked some dictionaries. Can you show us what you've found so far? ところで・・「濡らす」もあるよね～

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 湿らす (or its intransitive counterpart 湿る) is a matter-of-fact verb that means "to make/become (mildly) wet".
- 濡らす (or its intransitive counterpart 濡れる) is "to make/become (hardly/drippingly) wet".
- 潤す (or its intransitive counterpart 潤う) is used with a narrower range of objects that are considered "unhealthy" when dry, e.g., skin, lip, throat, meat, earth. In other words, 潤す means supplying water to something and putting it into a healthy moist status. The kanji 潤 has a clearly positive connotations (see: [潤い](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%BD%A4%E3%81%84)). 潤す even means "to (financially) enrich", "to (psychologically) comfort", etc., too.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just found that it is also 濡らす, will it be ok to ask about an answer for that too? how does this word different from the two above

Comment: @Smiled_One Added 濡れる/濡らす. 湿る always refers to mild wetness/moistness. Soaking wetness is always 濡れる, but 濡れる has a broader meaning.